# System hangs on boot, black/purple screen

Tags: boot

I can't boot my system. I set nomodeset and removed splash/quiet in GRUB. That causes a lot of boot text to go by, then the screen goes blank and that's it. Attempting to get to the shell (ctrl+alt+f1) does nothing.

In recovery mode, I can activate the root shell. Any other choice (dpkg, fsck, grub, whatever) hangs immediately after showing the status of the drive. This is all I get:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/sdc1: clean, ... files, ... blocks
_
```

And it just stops there. The only other filesystem listed in fstab is the swap partition. The only sign of any trouble is, during booting into recovery mode: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdc': Invalid argument

I don't know if that's a problem or not.

Any suggestions about where to start on fixing this?